# как избежать записывания в стейт значения из пропсов в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

как избежать записывания в стейт значения из пропсов в данном случае.  Если я передаю в пропсах focused , то его состояние в начальном стейте должно быть true, если нет, то false

```
state = {
  focused: this.props.focused || false
};

onFocus = event => {
  this.setState({focused: true});
  this.props.input.onFocus(event);
};

onBlur = event => {
  this.setState({focused: false});
  this.props.input.onBlur(event);
};

<Input
  focused={this.state.focused}
  onFocus={this.onFocus}
  onBlur={this.onBlur}
/>;
```

Comment: что-то непонятна задача. хорошо бы написать ясно что вы хотите получить и зачем. Как эти два методы связаны с условием, зачем их убирать, если вначале вопрос был вообще про другое?

Comment: сейчас в стейте у меня так


 focused: this.props.focused || false,

Comment: как этого избежать

Comment: а в чём смысл || false?

Comment: но даже без учёта || false вопрос неясен, непонятно откуда у вас эти пропсы берутся, и чего именно вы хотите избежать. И это желательно не тут в комментарии ответить а сразу в вопросе указать, что бы люди понимали о чём вы пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы ходите при монтировании компонента установить `this.state.focused` в зависимости от пропсов, но чтобы в дальнейшем пропсы в стейт не прокидывались? Если так, то вам поможет метод компонента `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.setState({focused: this.props.focused ? this.props.focused : false})
}
```

Этот метод вызывается один раз при монтировании компонента.